# ASP.NET and distributed caching in more than one web server

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached, web-farm, distributed-caching

I need distributed cache to be used in more than one web server.

I've tried a file based cache dependency, but it doesn't work in UNC path. I think .NET can not monitor the files on the UNC path.

I know that Microsoft has presented a new feature in Velocity. But, is there any other solution (like memcache in PHP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [memcached providers](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/) for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that "Velocity" is now a final, shipping product? It's part of [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx).

- [Installing, Configuring and Using Windows Server AppFabric and the "Velocity" Memory Cache](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m using shared hosting services and I can’t force them to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/asp-net-cache.html). A free express version is available for up to two servers.

EDIT: I just realized you cannot install anything. NCache needs installation on the server as well.